# Why doesn't Python like line 31?

Tags: python

Why doesn't Python like the commented print line when it is uncommented and the other line is not there?

```
# This is a guess the number game
import random

guessesTaken = 0

myName = input('Hi there! What is your name?')


number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well ' + myName + ' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20')


while guessesTaken < 6:
    guess = int(input('Try and guess what it is!')) # There are 4 spaces in front of print.
    # guess = int(input ())


    guessesTaken = guessesTaken + 1

    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low') # There are 8 spaces in front of print.

    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high')

    if guess == number:
        break   

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken)
   # print('Good Job, ' + myName + '!  You guessed my number ' + number + ' in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')  
    print('Good Job, ' + myName + '!  You guessed my number in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print('I am sorry.  The number I was thinking of was ' + number + ' Thanks for playing, though.')   

input('\n\nPress Enter to exit')
```

Comment: Do you get an error message (traceback)? If so, please edit your post to include it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. To show code properly, enter (copy'n'paste) it into the question, then use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent so it looks like code. With a question like this, it is helpful to annotate which is line 31 (though I see your question, as opposed to the title, does identify the line more clearly). It is also helpful to show the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 5):

Because `number` is an integer. Turn it into a string too:

```
print('Good Job, ' + myName + '!  You guessed my number ' + str(number) + ' in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
```

However, it'd be much better to use [`str.format()` string formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print('Good Job, {0}!  You guessed my number {1} in {2} guesses!'.format(
    myName, number, guessesTaken))
```

String formatting converts inputs for you; see the [Format String Syntax documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more details on what formatting options you have.

Comment: Also, as a matter of style, it would be better to replace that line with `print('Good Job, {}!  You guessed my number {} in {} guesses!',format(myName, number, guessesTaken)`. You don't need the `str` this way.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: Way ahead of you.

Comment: Why doesn't it have to be that way in this line?     print('I am sorry.  The number I was thinking of was ' + number + ' Thanks for playing, though.')

Comment: Because the line just before it replaced `number` with `str(number)`.

Answer (score 1):

`number` is an integer. You can't add integers and strings, as *the error message you received almost certainly told you.*

Convert it to a string using `str(number)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `number` is an integer. As the error message you received stated, you can't add integers and strings together.

You can convert it into a string using `str(number)` like I have done below.

This is what it should be:

```
print('Good Job, ' + myName + '!  You guessed my number ' + str(number) + ' in ' + guessesTaken + ' guesses!')
```